# "Undefined real result" with inverse() function in WinBUGS

Tags: markov-process, matrix, posterior, matrix-inverse, bugs

Using WinBUGS, I'd like to generate the posterior distribution for a function of several other variables (stochastic nodes). One step in building up this function involves taking the inverse of a matrix, using the `inverse()` command.

However, when I run the code with this line included, the model immediately generates the TRAP error "undefined real result". [As this indicates likely numerical overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969600/bugs-error-messages), I assume that a number with a very large number of decimal places is being generated. I have therefore tried to round numbers to only a few decimal places to see if it avoids the problem, but - so far - to no avail.

How can I avoid numerical overflow when taking the inverse of a matrix in WinBUGS?

The model runs fine without this line. I can obtain posterior distributions for all the separate variables that comprise this function, but not the function itself.

---

In case it is important info, here are the specific details:

- The value I want to estimate in WinBUGS is the expected first passage time of a Markov chain, using the so-called 'fundamental matrix' method (I am following the matrix methods in the Grinstead & Snell 2006 online textbook).
- To generate this matrix of interest, I subtract a 7-by-7 matrix `Q` of probabilities from a 7-by-7 identity matrix `I`, generating a new matrix called `IminusQ` and then take the inverse of this.
- The code for this step is: `FundamentalMatrix[SAMPLE,1:7,1:7] <- inverse(IminusQ[SAMPLE,,])`

The first part of the TRAP error that is generated is this:

```
undefined real result

 Math.Sqrt   [00000120H]
.x  REAL    -11.23763793679807

 MathMatrix.LUDecomp   [00000384H] 
.a  ARRAY 20, 20 OF REAL    Elements
.i  INTEGER 5
.j  INTEGER 5
.k  INTEGER -1
.size   INTEGER 7
.sum    REAL    -11.23763793679807

 MathMatrix.Invert   [000004DFH] 
.a  ARRAY 20, 20 OF REAL    Elements
.i  INTEGER 6415876
.j  INTEGER 0
.k  INTEGER 0
.size   INTEGER 7
.sum    REAL    0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the answer was that inverse() will not work with a nonsymmetric matrix - something I should have realised from the WinBUGS manual.